# Как сравнить значения списка строки датафрейма с константным значением?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Имеется датафрейм с колонкой содержащей список значений.
Примерно такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно создать новую колонку, в которой будет сравниваться константное значение с каждым значением списка. Если все значения списка => константного, то True иначе False.

Константное значение имеет тип float.

Пример датафрейма: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BBm1nZbPMQRO0w

Answer (score 1):

Например можно сделать вот таким образом: создадим новый столбец датафрейма под названием `isMoreThanConst`, в который поместим список булевых значений выражений `min('список') >= const` (очевидно, что если наименьший элемент массива больше или равен константе, то остальные и подавно будут). Итого получим примерно вот такой код:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'list': [[0.9999263286590576, 0.9998618364334106, 0.9998658895492554, 0.9999045133590698, 0.9999297857284546, 0.9999910593032837, 0.9999969005584717, 0.9991536140441895],
                 [0.9998722076416016, 0.9997316002845764, 0.9999145269393921, 0.9999016523361206, 0.9998788833618164, 0.9998179078102112, 0.9999963045120239, 0.9999744892120361, 0.5516145825386047],
                 [0.9998689889907837, 0.9999439716339111, 0.9998915195465088, 0.999955415725708, 0.999858021736145, 0.9727897047996521, 0.9992432594299316, 0.9994813799858093, 0.9996439218521118]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
const = 0.99

isMoreThanConst = [min(lst) >= const for lst in data['list']]
df['isMoreThanConst'] = isMoreThanConst

df
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: если данные берутся из csv, то пишем таким образом, чтобы преобразовать в список:

```py
csv_data = pd.read_csv('data_example.csv')
lsts = csv_data['symbol_scores'].values.tolist()

for i in range(len(lsts)):
    lsts[i] = lsts[i][1:-1] # избавляемся от [ и ] для удобства
    lsts[i] = list(map(float, lsts[i].split(','))) # и превращаем в нормальный список вещ. чисел

data = {'list': lsts}
...
```

Comment: Примерно такой вариант тоже пробовал. Проблема заключается в том, что при распаковке списка значений получаем строки и при сравнении их с float получаю ошибку:  '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float

Comment: @spacenew в таком случае перед взятием списка следует предварительно обратить все строки в вещественные числа: `[float(x) for x in lst]`, `map(float, lst)` или же `np.array(lst)`

Comment: Конвертировать тип тоже пробовал, получил ошибку: could not convert string to float: '[0.9999366998672485

Comment: @spacenew то есть все списки отправляются в одну строку или же каждый список превращается в отдельную строку?

Comment: Вот пример датафрейма https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BBm1nZbPMQRO0w. Каждой значение сравнивается с константой.

Comment: @spacenew обновил ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136169/discussion-between-4500zenja-and-spacenew).

Answer (score 1):

потестируйте на ваших данных такой вариант (с примером работает):

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

limit = 0.9
df = pd.read_csv('data_exmple.csv',index_col='Unnamed: 0')
df['over_limit'] = df.symbol_scores.map(lambda x: min(literal_eval(x))) >= limit

>>> df
'''
      id                                      symbol_scores  over_limit
580  581  [0.3578193187713623, 0.9660767912864685, 0.293...       False
581  582  [0.9996286630630493, 0.9998444318771362, 0.999...        True
582  583  [0.9998190999031067, 0.9998939037322998, 0.999...        True
```

Answer (score 1):

Сравнение для каждого значения списка поэлементно

```
val = 0.5
df["compare"]=df["symbol_scores"].str.extractall('(\d+\.+?\d+)').groupby(level=0)[0].apply(lambda x: [float(y)>val for y in x])
```

df:

```
   Unnamed: 0   id                                      symbol_scores                                            compare
0         580  581  [0.3578193187713623, 0.9660767912864685, 0.293...    [False, True, False, False, True, False, False]
1         581  582  [0.9996286630630493, 0.9998444318771362, 0.999...  [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, Tru...
2         582  583  [0.9998190999031067, 0.9998939037322998, 0.999...  [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, Tru...
```

Сравнение для всех значений списка:

```
df["compare"]=df["symbol_scores"].str.extractall('(\d+\.+?\d+)').groupby(level=0)[0].apply(lambda x: all([float(y)>val for y in x]))
```

df:

```
   Unnamed: 0   id                                      symbol_scores  compare
0         580  581  [0.3578193187713623, 0.9660767912864685, 0.293...    False
1         581  582  [0.9996286630630493, 0.9998444318771362, 0.999...     True
2         582  583  [0.9998190999031067, 0.9998939037322998, 0.999...     True
```